# On maximum independent set of line graphs

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, polynomial-time

Are there any special algorithms for maximum independent set of line graphs? Could this special case be in $\mathsf{P}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding a maximum independent set in $L(G)$ is equivalent to finding a maximum matching in $G$. For more, and a fast polynomial-time algorithm that work for e.g., line graphs, see [1].

---

[1] [Lozin, V.V. and Milanič, M., 2008. On finding augmenting graphs. Discrete Applied Mathematics, 156(13), pp.2517-2529.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X0800139X)